# asymptote problem?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I was curious about this exercise, because I thought it could be a valuable tool to use the theorem dell'asintoto ... I do not think that is the way, does anyone have any idea? !

Let $ h $ is a function defined on $(a, + \infty)$ and limited all intervals $(a, b)$

$a <$ b. Prove that if
$$ \lim_ {x \to + \infty} [h (x +1)-h (x) ] = k, $$

then $$\lim_ {x \to + \infty} \frac {h (x)}{x} =k$$

Comment: "limited all intervals $(a,b)$"?

Comment: I interpret that to mean bounded on all intervals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\epsilon>0$.  There is an $N$ such that if $x>N$, then $|h(x+1)-h(x)-k|<\epsilon$.  Therefore, $$|h(y+n)-h(y)-kn|=\left|\sum_{i=1}^{n}(h(y+i)-h(y+i-1))-k\right|\leq n\epsilon$$ for $y>N+1$.

Suppose that $A<h(x)<B$ when $y\in [N+1,N+2]$.  If $y\in [N+1+n,N+2+n]$, we then have $A-n\epsilon<h(y)-nk<B+n\epsilon$.  Adding $nk-yk$ and dividing by $y$ (assuming that $y>0$), we have

$$\frac{A-n\epsilon +(n-y)k}{y} < \frac{h(y)}{y}-k < \frac{B+n\epsilon +(n-y)k}{y}.$$

Since $y-n\in [N+1,N+2]$ and $\frac{n}{y}<\frac{y-N}{y}<1+\frac{|N|}{y}$, we therefore have

$$\left|\frac{h(y)}{y}-k\right| < \frac{\max(|A|,|B|)+|N|+2}{y}+\epsilon \left(1+\frac{|N|}{y}\right).$$

For large values of $y$,  $\frac{\max(|A|,|B|)+|N|+2}y<\epsilon$ and $1+\frac{|N|}y<2$, so

$$\left|\frac{h(y)}{y}-k\right|<3\epsilon.$$

Since we can do this for every $\epsilon>0$, we must have $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to \infty} h(x)/x=k$.

Comment: In your second line, you mean
$$|h(y+n) - h(y) - kn| = \left| \sum_{i=1}^n (h(y+i) - h(y+i-1) - k)\right| \le n \epsilon$$

Comment: @Robert Israel: Yes, thank you.